# C# OOP - Best way to identify the type of class in a list

Tags: c#, object-oriented

Suppose that I have 3 classes; 
class A, B which inherits from A, and C which also inherits from A.

And I have a mixed list of B and C instances contained under a list of A.

What is the best way to identify the inherited class when iterating over the list of A?

1) Store a 'type' enum property in the inherited classes and statically type-cast them based on this property

2) Use 'is' or 'as' keyword when iterating the list

Comment: Why wouldn't (2) be the obvious choice?

Comment: If you have a perfectly abstracted collection of A, why you need to relay on implementation details - derived classes? Your problem can be considered as "ringing bell" that something gone wrong with a design.

Comment: @RobertHarvey there may be a case when I only need to know the type of the child instance, where in this situation I do not need to actually cast the object at all, which would save a lot of performance in a large list due to difference of performance in comparing enums values and dynamic casting.

Comment: There are more choices: (3) change the `A` interface so it can control and/or interact with all of them regardless of their true type (with `B` and `C` each having appropriate overrides); (4) maintain a separate list of `B` and/or `C` so you know for sure what you have.

Comment: @Fabio Currently B and C have a very different implementation detail, but needs to be contained in a same, mixed collection and their order in the collection matters. Is there any better way to design this?

Comment: It depend on the way A, B and C  instances used in iteration. Can you show  how you iterate and use them?

Comment: @furibaito client code should not need to care about those differences in implementation details. If it does that's a smell in your code and you should consider redesigning it. If after careful consideration you decide that client code caring about implementation details is OK you should give a detailed explanation about that in the question.

Comment: There is yet another way: you can add properties for your classes to overwrite that allows the client code to decide how to interact with them.

Comment: @Theraot Yes you can. [Please don't](http://wiki.c2.com/?PolymorphismVsSelectionIdiom).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to identify the type of an object in a list is to not care which type you have in the list.  The point of polymorphism is that you can treat B and C the same. They know what they are. You don't have to ask them.  You tell them to do things and they sort out how to do it on their own.  This is called [tell, don't ask](https://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask).

If you have something you need to do depending on which type you have that something should be pushed into A, B, and C. It shouldn't be wandering around outside in the using code. Do that and you have no reason to ask which you have. Your using code starts to get very simple and making all these classes starts to make sense.

Otherwise you might as well not be making classes at all. It's a lot of work to do if you're not going to get anything for it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However I'm still confused to apply true OO-style to this problem: Suppose A is a class and B, C, D are the child class of A, I have a list with the child types [ B, D, null, D, C, B, null, D, C] and I need to reorder them based on their type in the list into [ B, B, C, C, D, D, D, null, null ]. This is trivial if I can iterate and ask the type of them, but how can I tell them to reorder themselves?

Comment: Who said you could put null in the list? This only works when you can treat them all the same.  You need the list to be homogeneous.  If you sometimes have to do nothing then instead of `null` use [Null Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).  It's my favorite design pattern.

Comment: As for sorting, if there is a primary way they should be sorted look into using `IComparable`.  If there are many ways look into [using a lambda with sort](http://stackoverflow.com/a/925477/1493294)

Comment: @furibaito Why would you ever need to order a list by type? Class type is an implementation concern, not business logic.